# Алгоритм работы кода Python

Tags: python, циклы, for, print

Объясните пожалуйста алгоритм работы данного кода:

```
a = [0,1,2,3]
for a[2] in a:
    print(a[3])
```

На выходе получается:

```
3
3
3
3
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Создали список чисел. `a = [0,1,2,3]`
2. Вывели четвертое число из списка столько раз, сколько элементов в списке.
3. На каждой итерации значение третьего элемента списка меняется, в конечном итоге третий элемент списка будет равен четвертому элементу списка.

---

Но по-моему код какой-то странный.

Answer (score 1):

Алгоритм простой. Этот цикл развёртывается в такой линейный код:

```py
a = [0,1,2,3]
a[2] = a[0]
# a = [0,1,0,3]
print(a[3])
a[2] = a[1]
# a = [0,1,1,3]
print(a[3])
a[2] = a[2]
# a = [0,1,1,3]
print(a[3])
a[2] = a[3]
# a = [0,1,3,3]
print(a[3])
```

Вообще цикл странный, непонятно, зачем заменять элемент списка `a[2]`, если он никак не используется.